# What is the recommended release definition for starting and stopping an Azure VM?

Tags: azure-devops, ms-release-management

I'd like to enhance the release definition so that I don't need to have a separate environment that only starts an Azure VM.

If we take a scenario where we have a Test, Beta, Production environments.  The client wants the application to be installed in Beta and Production on their local network.  We internally want a Test environment to run E2E tests against, allow for non-technical folks to exercise the app without needing VPN access to the customer beta environment, etc.

So here we have Environment followed by where the Agent is running:

`Test             - Azure VM
Beta             - Client machine
Production       - Client machine`

How we've solved this is to install the VSTS Agent on a machine at the client, which allows us to target that agent queue in the Beta and Production environments defined for that release.  Then we typically build an Azure VM and target that agent queue for the Test environment.

We don't want to run that Azure VM 24/7/365.  However if it's not running, then it can't respond to requests from Release Management.

What I've done is to create a environment named `Start Test VM` and `Stop Test VM` that use the `Azure Resource Group Deployment` to start and stop the VM.  Those 2 additional environments can have their agent queue set to `Hosted`.

I'd like to figure out how to combine the first 3 environments into a logical `Test` instead of having to create 3 release management environments.

`Start Test VM    - Hosted
Test             - Azure VM
Stop Test VM     - Hosted
Beta             - Client machine
Production       - Client machine`

The problem is that can be rather ugly and confusing when handing this over to one of our PM's or even myself when I circle back around 3 months later and think, "What the hell is this environment?  Oh it's just there to start/stop the VM."

Options:

1. Stay with status quo - keep it like it is, it can't be fixed
2. We could open up a port on the Azure VM and use Powershell remoting.  Then run on the Hosted agent or on an on-premise agent to start the VM, then deploy the application, then stop the VM.  - we really dislike this because the deployment would not be the same as the client on-premise deploy.  We'd like each environments' tasks to be the same, just with different variables.

Comment: Is the test environment hosted by Azure? If yes, why not deploy the build to it via the Hosted agent directly?

Comment: The test environment is hosted by Azure.  So you are advocating option #2?  This would involve using powershell remoting then and the build steps would be different no?  For example, we have a bunch of files for the web application - in the client environment we just copy those files to the target machine via UNC path, in Azure you can't copy the files via  UNC from the Hosted agent to your Azure VM.

Comment: You can use "AzureVMs File Copy" task to copy files to Azure VM.

Comment: Ok that solves problem one.  Now we need to configure things like an idempotent script to create the IIS App Pool if it doesn't exist, set Windows Authentication on it, Publish the dacpac, etc.  When it's executing from the context of the machine it's being installed, ie. being run from the VSTS Agent on the VM the script looks one way.  When the VSTS Agent is on Hosted and trying to control the VM remotely the script would look different no?

Comment: Wait...  if iirc, when remoting you can pass it a script, and that script gets physically copied to the remote machine and then executed from that remote machine as if you were executing directly... this might work, that way the set of scripts to deploy the application would be the same, except for the 'Test' environment would have a 'wrapper' script(s) that would use remoting to copy the script up.

Comment: wait again... the issue is we surely could to remoting but not out of the box tasks like Dacpac, etc.   So basically we'd have a custom set of tasks etc to for the 'Test' environment, and Beta and Production. /sigh - I love to set the 'Agent' on a task not on the 'Environment' so I could execute the first and last task of a release on a different Agent than the middle tasks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we've currently settled on is to continue with having an `environment` that isn't really what I would consider an environment, but more of a `stage` in the release pipeline that starts and/or shuts down a VM.  We run that on a `hosted` agent so it can start the VM and make sure to check `Skip artifacts download` on the `environment`.

For a continuous integration build, we set a chain so the VM gets started, CI `environment` gets kicked off and then VM gets stopped.  The remaining `environments` are then manually deployed up the chain as desired.

So here's an example:

- Start CI VM
- CI
- Stop CI VM
- Beta
- Production

And here's an image of how it looks in Release Management as of 2016.06.27:

[image]

I put single quotes around `environment` because I think I agree with [this user voice request](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/13828065-rename-environment-in-release-to-stage-or-some) in that, it's really more of a stage in the release pipeline.  Much like database development, the logical and the physical don't necessarily map 1 to 1.

Comment: As of today, 2016.10.11, I see we now have the concept of phases!  A phase has an assigned agent and you can have multiple phases in an environment therebye solving the exact issue of having bogus environments just to run things on different agents.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Azure PowerShell" and "Azure SQL Database Deployment" tasks to configure your Azure VM and SQL or call other script to run on the Azure VM.

There isn't any way to set the agent for tasks. You can submit a feature request on [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services) for this.

And another way to reduce the environment is that: if you deploy every build linked to the release, then you can add "Start Test VM" task into your build definition to start the VM when build is successful and add "Stop Test VM" task into "Beta" environment.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Eddie.  It created some interesting conversations at the office.  In the end we went with what I answer I posted.